# beforeEach is being called for every test instead of just once

Tags: javascript, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm encountering a situation when I use the `beforeEach` async and I have a couple of tests in my spec.
I see that the `beforeEach` is getting called for each test that runs instead of only once before all the tests - what am I doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
describe("desc1", function () {

   beforeEach((done) => {
   // some logic
        done();

    });

}
describe("desc2",() => {

    it("has a value", () => {
        expect().toBe('');
    });
    it("has a value", () => {
        expect().toBe('');
    });
    it("has a value", () => {
        expect().toBe('');
    });

});        
});
```

});

I'm using Typescript as you can see and Chutzpa

Comment: In mocha there is before hook and beforeEach hook, so might be there will be something before hook in the typescript

Comment: beforeEach will get called for every test

Comment: Ok. So in my beforeEach, I have scripts which are loaded async. I can check to see if it's my first test and load them but I was just wandering if there's a way to call beforeEach once for the describe.

Comment: within describe just user before(done){ //what you want to do  done()} for each describe it will run only once for each describe before the test

Comment: It looks like "before" is not recognized. There's a beforeSuite: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-before-suite

Comment: Ok then use that beforeSuite.From documentation it is telling it will be called once

Answer (score 2):

as the name says, "beforeEach" runs before-each-test, you should use "before"

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `before` command like so

```
describe('desc1', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.log('Logged Once Before All tests');
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.log('Logged Before Every test');
  })

  it("has a value", () => {
    expect().toBe('');
  });
  it("has a value", () => {
    expect().toBe('');
  });
  it("has a value", () => {
    expect().toBe('');
  });
});
```